# StaggeredGridView not scrolling after updating Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-gridview

I updated my flutter and dart package last night and now StaggeredGridView which was scrolling perfectly before is giving me an error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'SliverHitTestResult' is not a subtype of type 'BoxHitTestResult'
```

Comment: https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/issues/49

Comment: switch your channel to stable.

Comment: Thanks, But I am looking for an answer as well.

Comment: Try upgrading the package version to flutter_staggered_grid_view: "^0.3.0"

Answer (score 8):

i had the same problem , and i solved upgrading the version in pubspeck.yaml to flutter_staggered_grid_view 0.3.0

Comment: this is the solution

Answer (score 4):

The BoxHitTestResult exception was fixed in new version of flutter_staggered_grid_view **0.3.0**

You can check [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-changelog-tab-) here

If you have same issue after the upgrade,

run `flutter clean` in terminal and then run again.

Answer (score 1):

@Yamim comment: "switch your channel to stable" worked.

Here is the command you can use:

```
flutter channel stable
```

Other Channels:

```
$ flutter channel
Flutter channels:
  * stable
    beta
    dev
    master
```

For more information about channels you can refer: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in the upgraded package No need to modify the code just upgrade the package.

**Add the following dependencies to your pubspec.yaml and restart the application. It works well.**

```
flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.3.0
```